# off() not working in firefox but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a `beforeonload` function but I want when the user submits the form `beforeunload` shouldn't work. Here is my code, which works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
window.form_submitted = ''; 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        if (form_submitted == '') {
            return "Are you sure to leave that page";
        }
    });
});

jQuery('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).off('beforeunload');
    form_submitted = 1;
    site_redirect(resp.payment_url);
} 

return false;
});
```

Comment: Then you'll need to give more information. "That did not work" in not helpful. Have you debugged the code using breakpoints? Are the event handlers called? What does `site_redirect` do? Why is `form_submitted` and empty sting and then set to `1`? Why do you use both `form_submitted` and `.off()`?

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax issues, and you have to place the `submit` block inside the DOMReady handler, otherwise JS will attempt to bind the event to an element which doesn't yet exist in the DOM. Also note you can remove the the global flag variable as you are unbinding the `beforeunload` event on form submission. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        return "Are you sure to leave that page";
    });

    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(window).off('beforeunload');
        site_redirect(resp.payment_url);
    }); 
});
```

Also note that by doing a redirect when the form is submit (assuming that's what the `site_redirect` function is doing) then the content of the form will be lost.